# WebRTC Chrome and Firefox connection.setRemoteDescription

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

Here is how I accept the created offer and create an answer:

```
var description = new RTCSessionDescription(sdp),
    self = this;
connection.setRemoteDescription(description, function () {
  connection.createAnswer(function (answer) {
    try {
      connection.setLocalDescription(answer, function () {
        self._mediator.sendSDPAnswer({
          data: answer,
          connection: connection.id
        });
        self._isRemoteDescriptionSet[connection.id] = true;
        self._setIceCandidates(connection);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      self._logger.error('Error while setting the remote description', e);
    }
  }, function (error) {
    throw error;
  }, {
    mandatory: {
      OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
      OfferToReceiveAudio: true
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately when I create the offer by Firefox in Chrome I get:

```
Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set data send codecs..
```

In Firefox I initiate the connection by:

```
  connection.createOffer(function (offer) {
    connection.setLocalDescription(offer, function () {
      mediator.sendSDPOffer({
        data: offer,
        connection: connection.id
      });
    });
  }, function (error) {
    throw new Error('Error while connecting', error);
  }, {
    mandatory: {
      OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
      OfferToReceiveAudio: true
    }
  });
```

The peer connection I create by:

```
  this._connection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers,
    { optional: [
      { RtpDataChannels: true },
      { DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true }
    ]});
```

When I try to initiate the session between Chrome browsers everything works.

Comment: what are the respective browser versions and the OS you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set rtpDataChannel to false and remove the DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement.

```
this._connection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers,
  { optional: [
  { RtpDataChannels: false }
]});
```